# WordPress - List Custom Type With Specific meta_key value

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, meta-key

So I have the following

```
SELECT wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_author,wp_posts.post_date,wp_posts.post_content,wp_posts.post_title,wp_posts.post_excerpt,wp_postmeta.meta_value
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.id=wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key='cm_video' and post_status='publish'
ORDER BY wp_posts.id DESC;
```

Which brings back what I need (almost). The meta_value is in the form

```
a:2:{s:4:"code";s:27:"http://youtu.be/xpiL05fCE1E";s:4:"type";s:7:"youtube";}
```

What's the easiest way to bring back just `http://youtu.be/xpiL05fCE1E`? There are various other values that can be present in here such as embed and iframe code.

Is there something internal to WordPress I should use?

I've come up with this which seems to do the trick. Thoughts?

```
SELECT 
wp_posts.ID, wp_posts.post_author,wp_posts.post_date,wp_posts.post_content,wp_posts.post_title,wp_posts.post_excerpt,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(wp_postmeta.meta_value, '";', 2), ':"', -1)
FROM wp_posts
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON wp_posts.id=wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key='cm_video' and post_status='publish'
```

Thanks

Comment: Is the returned pattern is same ? If yes then it could be done with mysql else it will be difficult to handle with mysql you may need to use application level to handle it.

Answer (score 0):

use unserialize() method

```
$a='a:2:{s:4:"code";s:27:"http://youtu.be/xpiL05fCE1E";s:4:"type";s:7:"youtube";}';
$a = unserialize($a);
print_r($a);

//output
Array ( [code] => http://youtu.be/xpiL05fCE1E [type] => youtube )

echo $a['code'];
```

Here are two types of variable

```
a = array and 2 is the dimension of the array
s = string and 4 is the length of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

We will get the same with a proper format with wp_query :

```
     $query = new WP_Query( array ( 
                                    'post_type' => 'product', 
                                    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num', 
                                    'meta_key' => 'cm_video' ) );

     print_r($query);
```

Now if $query object have the code elements in it with your value. Print it :

```
     echo $query->code;
```

Hope it will work for you please let me know if you need any further help.

Comment: It will be a good practice to use wordpress predefined function when you are using wp.